# How to auto-configure ConversionService in non-web Spring environment?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a non-web environment with `spring-boot`, as I only require some classes:

```
spring.main.web-application-type=none
```

Question: how can I tell spring to auto-configure the `org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService` (that I need eg for `@Convert` auto mappings of `@Entity` objects)?

When I try to autowire the conversation service, it fails:

```
@Autowired
private ConversionService conversionService;

public void fetch() {
     BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(MyObject.class, conversionService));
}
```

`required a bean of type 'org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService' that could not be found.`

Answer (score 1):

You can autowire ConfigurableEnvironment and get the conversion service from there.  If you want to make that available directly, put it in a Bean method.